# Calling a math library function from \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I am interested in plotting my own function with pgfplots in combination with the math library from TikZ&PGF. This function is something I would use many times in my document.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
% Defining the function
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
     function my_fun(\a, \b, \c) { return \a * exp(\b * \c); % <<< This is my function
};
% Plotting the function
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot { my_fun{\x, 1, 0} }; % <<< This is obviously wrong
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is this even possible? If not, what would you recommend as the best approach to creating a function that would be plotted (with different arguments) several times?

I would like to avoid the approach of using a series of `\def`'s with `#`-type arguments if at all possible.

Comment: you can also use TikZ' `declare function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As percusse already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418242/calling-a-math-library-function-from-addplot#comment1046179_418242) you can use `declare function` to achieve what you want. Here an example how to use it.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the LUA backend for calculation
        % (--> speed improvement)
        compat=1.12,
        % declare your function here ...
        /pgf/declare function={
            MyFun(\a,\b,\c) = \a * exp(\b*\c);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {MyFun(x, 1, 0)};
        \addplot {MyFun(x, 1, 1)};
        \addplot {MyFun(1, x, 1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]